# iOS in-app purchase auto redirect to App Store application

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I researched iOS in-app purchase and implemented this function in my game, following [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_in_app_purchase.htm).

When I tested the app, I had already signed out of my iTunes account (in settings/store). I opened my app, purchased an item and logged into my test account (iTunes Connect --> my account use is Japanese account and my app in iTunes Connect is set to distribute in Japan).

After login success, iOS auto redirects to the App Store (hidden my game) --> this is an issue because it didn't use normal flow when use in-app purchase.

My iOS version is 5.1.1 and I use XCode 4.6.

*PS: after debugging, I found that my app already loaded the product using the ProductID from iTunes.*

Anyone seen this problem? Please help me solve this issue.
Thank in advance!

Comment: In your application u have any predefined URLs...

Comment: No, i only defined ProductID (created in itunes connect) to get it from Itunes. Something like below:
SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                                     initWithProductIdentifiers: [NSSet setWithObject: kXcoinBagSmall]];

Comment: please debug and check the result of request.

Comment: We are hosted the application through OTA Enterprise In-house Distribution. so i dont know much about Appstore distribution.

Answer (score 0):

In-app purchases can only be used in applications which are purchased through the iOS App Store. Enterprise applications cannot use IAP.